# Jquery/ajax page call not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to get another page to call into a div on a page, I have done this multiple times before and had no problem with it but it just refuses to work this time.

Can anyone see a reason why it is not loading into my div.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function new(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "map.php",
           success: function(msg){
                $("#map").html(msg);
           }
      });
}
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="new()">
<div id="map" style="width: 40px; height: 100px; background: blue;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Any help would be much appreciated**

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: what are the errors on your console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can name a function `new` as this is a reserved keyword. Try renaming it to something that's not a reserved keyword e.g `loadNewPageData()` .

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I didn't even think of keywords, it is always the most obvious problems that get you :D - thank you for your help!